# Using jQuery to control HTML5 <audio> volume

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-slider

Okay, I want to control the volume of an HTML5 element using the jQuery Slider element. I have implemented the slide, but can't figure out how to make the value of the slider take the place of the "audio player.volume = ?".

Any help is much appreciated.

[**Source**](http://www.julake.co.uk/media/loader.php?page=contact)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `volume` property is like opacity, it goes between zero and one, one being 100%.

Your code is so close, you just need to divide `value` by `100` when setting the volume of the `<audio>` element:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    value  : 75,
    step   : 1,
    range  : 'min',
    min    : 0,
    max    : 100,
    change : function(){
        var value = $("#slider").slider("value");
        document.getElementById("audio-player").volume = (value / 100);
    }
});
```

Notice I also put the `change` event handler inside the initialization of the `slider` widget.

When I paste the above code along into the console while on your webpage, and the volume slider worked as expected.

Also, you can bind to the `slide` event and the volume will change as the user slides the `slider` widget, not just after they finish moving the handle:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    value : 75,
    step  : 1,
    range : 'min',
    min   : 0,
    max   : 100,
    slide : function(){
        var value = $("#slider").slider("value");
        document.getElementById("audio-player").volume = (value / 100);
    }
});
```

Comment: Works, brilliantly.
However, if you click randomly on the bar, obviously, the slider moves and the volume adjusts, but if you go down a few times, the volume will go down, but if you then go up once, it goes down again, then back up.
The slider works fine though.

EDIT: Fixed this by adding both the slide and change into the initialisation.


@Jasper

Comment: Works great for me! Used this with a custom jQuery UI theme for the slider, and just like that I have a custom volume slider for the MP3 playing in the background.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a **[quick jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yv6Rt/)** (note: the audio begins on page load).

jQuery:

```
$('#audioSlider').slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    value: audio1.volume,
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    range: 'min',
    animate: true,
    step: .1,
    slide: function(e, ui) {
        audio1.volume = ui.value;
    }
});​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="audioSlider"></div>

<audio id="audio1" autoplay>
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html5/song.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html5/song.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>​
```

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery you can get the DOM object by simply using

```
$("audio")[0]
```

So an example would be:

**html**

```
 <div class="audio-clip">
    <h4>Clip 1</h4>
    <input type="button" class="play-button">Play</button>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1"/>
    <audio src="http://www.w3schools.com/html5/song.mp3"></audio>
 </div>
 <div class="audio-clip">
    <h4>Clip 2</h4>
    <input type="button" class="play-button">Play</button>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1"/>
    <audio src="http://www.w3schools.com/html5/song.mp3"></audio>
 </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".play-button").click(function(){
        $(this).parent("div").find("audio").trigger('play');    
    });

    $(".audio-clip input[type='range']").on("input", function(){
        $(this).parent("div").find("audio")[0].volume = this.value;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be achieved with a simple input range element, without using jQuery-UI.

```
<input id="volumeSlider" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.3" />


let audioStream = new Audio('https://mofosounds.com:8000/;');

$("#volumeSlider").change(function(){
    let volume = $(this).val();
    audioStream.volume = volume ;
});
```