# volume control for html5 jquery music player

Tags: jquery, html, volume, audio-player

I`m using the music player  html5 jquery music player for my website.But I found that there is no option to control the volume for the music player.Could any one please help me to include an external volume control for the  html5 jquery music player.

Here you can find the demo for  html5 jquery music player

http://www.codebasehero.com/files/music-player-1.0.1/demo/

Comment: The solution to this can be found in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589292/using-jquery-to-control-html5-audio-volume)

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, you can create a function in your script tag like the following...

```
var audio = document.getElementById("player");
$('.volume-up').click(function() {
    audio.volume+=0.1;
    return false;
});
$('.volume-down').click(function() {
    audio.volume-=0.1;
    return false;
});
```

now you can create two anchor tags `<a>` with the above classes like so...

```
<a class="volume-up" href="#">Turn it up!</a>
<a class="volume-down" href="#">Turn it down!</a>
```

Comment: Since you're using jquery, you can also do this to get the audio object: var audio = $("#player").get(0);