# Set volume of html 5 audio tag with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using jQuery to control HTML5 <audio> volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589292/using-jquery-to-control-html5-audio-volume)

I have a html audio tag:

```
<audio class="audio" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" src="All_Right.mp3"></audio>
```

If it try to set the volume with Javascript like so:

```
$('.audio').volume = 0.1;

alert($('.audio').volume);
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you're using jQuery.

`$('.audio')` returns a jQuery object, not a DOM element.
Setting a property on a jQuery object has no effect on the DOM.

Instead, you need to call the jQuery `.prop(name, value)` method.