# How to mute/unmute sound of an audio using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I have created  a fiddle of my function here( http://jsfiddle.net/rhy5K/10/ ) . Now i want to provide the  Sound "Mute/unpute" option for users.  Example   if i click on "a link then sound playing like `Get ready,5,4,3,2,1`  should be mute and vice-versa.

I am thinking like to call a to `toggle_sound` function on click, but i am confuse like what should i write inside the function to mute the sound.

Please provide me a logic, or a solution for my problem.

**Explanation using code example:**

I want to MUTE/UnMUTE this  below sound playing

```
var playGetReady = function (done) {
    var ids = ['audiosource', 'a_5', 'a_4', 'a_3', 'a_2', 'a_1'],
        playNext = function () {
            var id = ids.shift();
            document.getElementById(id).play();
            if (ids.length) {
                setTimeout(playNext, 1000);
            } else {
                done();
            }
        };
    playNext();
};
```

**Warning: *This JS fiddle demo may play sound on load***

Comment: Use `document.getElementById(id).setVolume(0);` to mute

Comment: or `document.getElementById(id).muted = true;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10075909/how-to-set-the-loudness-of-html5-audio or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13937118/set-volume-of-html-5-audio-tag-with-javascript

Comment: @Ian okay i got it, now I want to check whether sound is playing or not, how to check ?

Comment: @rani I added a toggle volume handler in your jsfiddle, but it seems that your App class is not really functionnal already. Maybe if you work on a bit more, this could work : http://jsfiddle.net/rhy5K/25/

Comment: @Oliboy50  I am trying since last few mins for this but still not done.  May be if you also try for me then it wil be more helpfull. I can see you set `this.muted`, but you don't use it to prevent playing sound. I think You should check if it's muted like with `this.newTimer` in start method

Comment: @Ian is it possible to solve to update a fiddle for me? i could not solve this, since last 1 hour. Feeling very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Try HTML5 Video_tag for display video with audio.

Or this below example along with html5 with jQuery:

```
window.my_mute = false;

$('#my_mute_button').bind('click', function(){

    $('audio,video').each(function(){

        if (!my_mute ) {

            if( !$(this).paused ) {
                $(this).data('muted',true); //Store elements muted by the button.
                $(this).pause(); // or .muted=true to keep playing muted
            }

        } else {

            if( $(this).data('muted') ) {
                $(this).data('muted',false);
                $(this).play(); // or .muted=false
            }

        }
    });

    my_mute = !my_mute;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
document.getElementById(id).volume = 1;
```

or

```
document.getElementById(id).volume = 0;
```

Comment: but before applying this, how can i check whether the sound is playing or not?  Better can you update my fiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/rhy5K/10/) ?

Comment: those links i know, but you really want to help me means, plz update my fiddle with the answer as i wanted. Your link   does not solve my problem