# How to properly embedd audio stream into a web page, and set desired volume level?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, media-player, asx

How to properly embedd asx audio stream into a web page, and set desired volume level? I want set background music, the player should be hidden on web page. I tried sample code below, it works, but I can no set volume level - it always play at maximal volume. 
p.s. asx stream play without autostart parameter, too.

```
<embed src="http://top.tk/wma/audiostream.asx" width="0" height="0" autostart="true">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok , I find solution myself.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://flash-mp3-player.net/medias/player_mp3_js.swf" width="1" height="1">
    <param name="movie" value="http://flash-mp3-player.net/medias/player_mp3_js.swf" />
    <param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="FlashVars" value="mp3=http%3A//mysite.com/audio/file.mp3&amp;autoplay=1&amp;volume=30" />
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into using [HTML 5 Audio](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) elements, this has a volume property you can set and control using jQuery. See this [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589292/using-jquery-to-control-html5-audio-volume)

Answer (score 0):

```
<embed src="http://top.tk/wma/audiostream.asx" volume="XXX" width="0" height="0" autostart="true">
```

**XXX** being a value between 0 and 100.

Comment: I already tried this, it always play at max volume, regardless of volume value.