# Change volume on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, video

I want to change the volume on the fly, if I move the knob of the volume input. I have read a lot of posts and of course I googled.

```
document.getElementById('volume').addEventListener('change', function () {
   console.log(this.value);         
   video = document.getElementById('active');
   video.volume = this.value;
   //$('#active').prop("volume", this.value); //even this doesn't work.
});
```

With this code I can change the volume, when I do mouse up. But it won't change on the fly. How can I change on the fly? And main important why is it not working?

Comment: if the control you're using doesn't fire events on each change you could possible trigger on a mouse move or a timer when the control has focus...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post:

[Using jQuery to control HTML5 <audio> volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589292/using-jquery-to-control-html5-audio-volume)

Did you set the min/max volume already?