# jquery slider that controls html5 audio volume

Tags: jquery, html, audio, html5-audio, jquery-slider

I am creating a custom JQuery/HTML5 audio player and I want a slider that can control the volume of the audio element.  I have the slider that is tagged with `class="volume_slider"` and the songs are tagged with `class="audio-player"`.
For some reason this code will not change the volume, I got the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589292/using-jquery-to-control-html5-audio-volume), any ideas on why the volume isn't changing?

```
$(".volume_slider").slider({
    value  : 75,
    step   : 1,
    range  : 'min',
    min    : 0,
    max    : 100,
    slide  : function(){
        var value = $(".volume_slider").slider("value");
        $(".audio-player").volume = (value / 100);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing audio-player you are accessing the jQuery object, not the element itself. So instead set the property with, `$('.audio-player').prop('volume', (value/100));`